# Delete "Folder" on Amazon S3 with aws-sdk gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I'm able to delete individual files within a "Folder" on Amazon S3 using the following:

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'])
folder_path = 'uploads/'+@image.s3_filename
s3.buckets[ENV['AWS_BUCKET']].objects.with_prefix(folder_path).delete_all
```

but this leaves an empty folder. How can I just delete the folder entirely (folder_path)?

Answer (score 22):

This is an old question, but you can do this for aws-sdk 2.0>

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
folder = 'path/to/the/folder'
objects = s3.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']).objects({prefix: folder})
objects.batch_delete!
```

`delete` was depreciated

Hope this helps!

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. Thanks @Jeremie , saved some time for me.

Comment: Yep, this is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

Everything on S3 is an object you can manipulate by its "key". If you just grab it you can call `delete` on it:

```
s3.buckets[ENV['AWS_BUCKET']].objects["name of the folder"].delete
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but this doesn't seem to be working for me.  I tried passing in both the name of the folder ("test") and the path to the folder within the bucket ("uploads/test"), but neither worked.

Comment: I don't get an error when I try running the code; it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Did you try after delete_all object inside it?

Comment: yes, I can delete all objects inside the folder, just not the folder itself (as explained in the original post)

Comment: my mistake, it looks like the code I had posted originally was actually deleting the folder!  The s3 console just wasn't refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

You must delete all files in folder, after you can removed folder.

Comment: No need for that. See @Jeremie answer.